# How to Find Probability mass function from card problem?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

This is a problem with Probability. Question is like this:

Recall that there are 52 cards in a standard deck, with 4 cards for each denomination. Suppose that
you flip over the top 4 cards. This constitutes the first draw from the deck. Discard those cards that
are not a 2 and redraw new cards from the remaining deck so that you again have 4 cards flipped over.
Continue doing this until all 4 cards are a 2. Let X denote the number of draws made and $Y_j$ denote
the number of cards drawn on draw j. I am trying to solve the following problems

(a) Derive the pmf of $Y_2$.

(b) Derive the pmf of $Y_2|X$ ≥ 3.

In (a), I thought it is a binomial , like ${13\choose 2} *p^2(1-p)^{13-1}$
but I am not sure and after solving (a) I think the use that result in (b).
I need your suggestions. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a, you draw four cards the second time (so $Y_2=4$) unless there is at least one $2$ in the first draw.  What is the chance of no $2$'s in the first draw?  What is the chance of one $2$ in the first draw? In that case you have $Y_2=3$ and so on.  Your result should just be four numbers.  As the problem is stated, if you draw four twos on the first draw, you don't make the second and so $Y_2$ is undefined, not zero. b is just like a except you know that you do not draw four twos in the first two draws, which changes the probabilities a bit.